# flume how to collect kafka protobuf data

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, protocol-buffers, flume

there has some protobuf data in my kafka,the data is byte array,i want to use flume collect the kafka data to hdfs,and use spark analysis the hdfs data,after i use the flume config below

the flume configuration is

```
agent.sources = source_from_kafka
agent.channels = mem_channel
agent.sinks = hdfs_sink


agent.sources.source_from_kafka.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
agent.sources.source_from_kafka.batchSize = 100
agent.sources.source_from_kafka.kafka.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
agent.sources.source_from_kafka.kafka.topics = mytopic


agent.sources.source_from_kafka.kafka.serializer = io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer

agent.sources.source_from_kafka.kafka.consumer.group.id = mytopic_consumer


agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://XXXX/%{topic}/%Y%m%d/%Y%m%d%H

agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.rollSize = 130000000
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.rollInterval = 3600
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.batchSize = 100
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.threadsPoolSize = 30
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.callTimeout = 60000
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.idleTimeout=300
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.filePrefix = events

agent.channels.mem_channel.type = memory
agent.channels.mem_channel.capacity = 100
agent.channels.mem_channel.transactionCapacity = 100
agent.channels.mem_channel.byteCapacity = 800000
agent.channels.mem_channel.byteCapacityBufferPercentage = 20
agent.channels.mem_channel.keep-alive = 60

agent.sources.source_from_kafka.channels = mem_channel
agent.sinks.hdfs_sink.channel = mem_channel
```

I can see the data in the hdfs like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKeFe.png)
But when i use
sc.newAPIHadoopFileLongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat.map(_._2.copyBytes) to read the data and parse it to Protobuf ,the error is
msg: {���ֈ1�     *��/2ext{}
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)

can anyone know why,and how to resolve this

I want it works well

Comment: 1) Confluent Serializer requires a schema registry. Where are you setting that? 2) Spark can read from Kafka on its own, why do you need Flume?

Comment: 1.My proto is a nested proto，how to register the schema in the config file ? can you give me a demo? 2.i know spark streaming can read the kafka,but i want to save the kafka data on hdfs，So others can use it

Comment: Nesting shouldn't matter. I'm saying you've not configured `schema.registry.url` anywhere for using Confluent classes. And Kafka Connect (or Spark) can also read from Kafka **and _write** to HDFS_, so you didn't really answer my question about why Flume? (which doesn't document any Protobuf compatibility, last I checked)